# Move form to bottom right corner

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-xe7

I've been struggling for some time to move a run-time created form to the bottom right corner of the main form.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
//    procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
//    procedure WindowPosChanging(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F1 : TForm;
begin
   F1 := TForm.Create(nil);
   F1.Height := 300;
   F1.Width :=300;
   F1.Position := poDesktopCenter;
   F1.Name := 'asdf';
   F1.Left:=ClientOrigin.X;//+ ActiveControl.Left+ ClientOrigin.X;
   F1.Top:=ClientOrigin.Y;//+ClientOrigin.Y;
   F1.Show;
end;

//procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
//var
//  pt : TPoint;
//begin
//   pt := mOUse.CursorPos;
//   lABEL3.Caption := IntToStr(pt.X);
//   label4.Caption := IntToStr(pt.Y);
//end;
//
//procedure TForm1.WindowPosChanging(var Msg: TMessage);
//begin
//    Label1.Caption :=  IntToStr(ClientOrigin.X);
//    Label2.Caption :=  IntToStr(ClientOrigin.Y);
//end;

end.
```

So we have this example.

```
F1.Position := poDesktopCenter;
```

This command works perfectly if you want to center the form onto the desktop, but what i want to achive is position the `F1` form at the bottom corner of the main form. I can't figure out how to do it.

Something like this [image]

Comment: @SertacAkyuz How will poDesigned be usefull to the OP especially since the main form might not be on the same postion as it was at design time? Infact I strongly recomend of not using poDesigned at any time. Why? Becouse if your appliction is started on a monitor with smaller resolution the form might actually be positioned outside of visual area and therefore isn't accessible from user.

Comment: @Silver - I don't understand your question. If you want the form use the left and top you assigned, you have to set position 'poDesigned'.

Comment: Yes but OP is trying to position second form relative to its main form position while using of poDesigned positiones form using absolute screen position. And if you have been developing your application on screen size like 1900x1080 and at design time the form was positioned let us say at 1200:1000 running such application on a monitor with screen size of 1024x768 would lead to form being positioned outside of the visible area since its left and top position will be greater than screen width and height.

Comment: Besides how is design time form position even determined in newer Delphi version which use built in form designer and not as standalone winow as it was common in older Delphi versions.

Comment: @SilverWarior Sertac is right, Position must be set to poDesigned, otherwise the form will not position it self according to Left and Top. I'm just looking at a correction to my answer regarding non-parented position *inside* the other forms borders, but BorderWidth is *zero*!

Comment: @Tom - Use `ClientOrigin.X+ClientWidth-F1.Width;` and `ClientOrigin.Y+ClientHeight-F1.Height;` to account for bottom form borders.

Comment: @Sertac Thanks for the reminder, I knew there was something ...;)

Comment: @Silver Your argument against using fixed position for a form is a very valid one, but necessary in this case with a free floating form. Reminds me, I was once asked for a modification to save form position at shutdown. Ok, simple storing in the registry. Soon I was asked to add a new feature to force the form visible. Somebody worked with a laptop in the office on a secondary display and had some trouble on the road (without it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all cases below, use

```
F1.Position := poDesigned;
```

F1 parent = Form1, bottom-right inside Form1 borders

```
F1.Parent := self;
F1.Left := self.ClientWidth - F1.Width;
F1.Top  := self.ClientHeight - F1.Height;
```

`Self` is optional, but makes it clear that you refer to properties of Form1, in which context you are executing the code.

F1 parent not assigned, bottom-right with overlapping borders

```
F1.Left := Left + Width - F1.Width;
F1.Top  := Top + Height - F1.Height;
```

F1 parent not assigned, bottom-right inside the borders of Form1

```
F1.Left := ClientOrigin.X + ClientWidth - F1.Width;
F1.Top  := ClientOrigin.Y + ClientHeight - F1.Height;
```

Credit goes to Sertac for reminding me about ClientOrigin

Comment: @SertacAkyuz i've been busy with an other project. I'll get back with an answer when I have time to test it as I can't do it from home. I'll try do it tomorrow.

Comment: @TomBrunberg , i've tried your solution it works for what I've asked. But I just found that my form is not called from an other form, it's called froma DBGrid component that is align all client into a form => the Left/Top will always be 0.

Comment: i changed the self with a TWinControler which is assigned with the parent of the dbgrid and it works. TY